# Forwarded custom registered URL scheme didn't working as a Link in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios9, url-scheme

I need to share a link through my app to gmail. After that, clicking on the shared link open the app. I did this following a tutorial but the shared link is not behaving like a link. The way:

Registered the URL scheme:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>com.appName</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>appName</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

Send the mail using mailcomposer:

```
[body appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<a href=\"appName://appName.com/%@\">http://appName.com/%@</a><br><br>",parameter, parameter]];
```

I am able to send mail but the shared link is not shared as a link. It's shared as a normal text line. What is going wrong? please help.

Answer (score 1):

Custom URL schemes (like `appName://`) often aren't treated as links in other apps. What you could do instead is wrap that app-specific URL inside a link that other apps CAN recognize (beginning with `http://` or `https://`), and then issue some sort of redirect to your app's URL scheme. This is how we used to handle things at [Branch.io](https://branch.io).

Unfortunately this isn't a complete solution either, because iOS 9 introduced Universal Links and made URL schemes less functional. You'll probably need to implement both.

Comment: if I click the http:// link than how will the app response to the link?

Comment: If you configure Universal Links, iOS will trigger the app automatically based on the http:// URL itself. Otherwise you have to do some sort of redirection to the app URL scheme on the server hosting the http:// destination page. It's a bit of a pain to set up...definitely give Branch.io a look cause we automate all of that as a free service.